# Is timestamping possible without publishing?

Tags: timestamping

The Wikipedia article [Trusted Timestamping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) states that we can timestamp data by publishing it's hash. Publishing can be done either independently or via a third-party publisher, as explained by DrLector on [another thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/11917/2373).

However, can we timestamp data without the capability to publish anything?

What solutions can a person (or a computer) employ to timestamp data if it is not connected to the internet for several days or weeks?

Comment: http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/553.pdf $\;$